Running a SPA from a path other than root in .net 8
I'm trying to set up an experimental C# 8 server that would run Web API, Razor pages but also various React Apps off of specific paths (E.G. "/spa1") but can't get the SPA to serve off of a path. Base on what I've read in some related stack overflow questions listed below (and a few others), this should work.
*Note: My client Dir is {SolutionFolder}\projects\cs.web.client and the Web Server is {SolutionFolder}\projects\CS.Web.Server
public static class SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void EnableReactApp(this WebApplication app, string spaPath, string codePath, int serverPort, bool isDev = false)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(app);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(spaPath);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(codePath); 

        app.Map(new PathString(spaPath), client =>
        {
            client.UsePathBase(new PathString(spaPath));
            //client.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            client.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                var path = Path.Combine((Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))?.FullName ?? string.Empty, codePath);
                spa.Options.SourcePath = path;
                spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path)
                    {
                        UseActivePolling = true,
                    },
                    RedirectToAppendTrailingSlash = true,
                };

                if (isDev)
                {
                    spa.Options.DevServerPort = serverPort;
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("dev");
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

Program.CS
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
IMvcBuilder? views = builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
IMvcBuilder? pages = builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

#if (DEBUG)
views.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
pages.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
#endif

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.EnableReactApp("/spa1", "cs.web.client", 707, app.Environment.IsDevelopment());

app.Run();

And, indeed when I run this, I can see that vite is serving the react app at https://localhost:707 as it should. However, when I go to https://localhost:7788/spa1 I get this  error message: TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 120 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
My Razor pages and other API end points work correctly.
Related Questions I've been looking at:

How to host multiple React SPA apps on a single ASP.NET Core site?
How to handle multiple SPA application in ASP.NET Core

I've also tried to study what the template is doing to make sure I'm doing it correctly, but that wants to add "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" to the environment variables in the launch profile which requires all settings to be in the csproj file and this does not seem to have a way for you to set it to a specific path, nor would I be able to run multiple SPA's.
Here is my vite.config.ts
const baseFolder = env.APPDATA !== undefined && env.APPDATA !== ''
    ? `${env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
    : `${env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateName = "cs.web.client";
const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath) || !fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
    if (0 !== child_process.spawnSync('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
    ], { stdio: 'inherit', }).status) {
        throw new Error("Could not create certificate.");
    }
}

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:7788';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target,
                secure: false
            },
        },
        port: 707,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})

Thanks!

Make sure that the create-react-app server is configured to listen on the correct host and port. Verify that it is configured to serve the SPA from the correct path ("/spa1"). Ensure that there are no network-related issues preventing communication between the server and the create-react-app development server. Check firewall settings and network configurations to ensure that the necessary ports are open and accessible.

As stated in my post, the server is correctly responding to port 707 as specified in the code presented in the post. Can you be more concise about how I should check the react app is configured to serve from the correct path? Same for checking network related issues? they are both being hosted via Visual Studios on the same machine as outlined in the code in the post above. Considering that it is available to browse at port 707 I don't understand how this could be the issue.
Could you please provide detailed advice instead of generic advice?

you're moving up to a directory outside of the special "wwwrooot" directory there.  You'll want your paths to be inside of it.  So start at Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot".. add your subdirectories there.  Ex: Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/spa1".

Try adding a fallback endpoint, this tells the host, in this case the .net application, to fallback to /reactapp for paths that are not defined in the razor pages.
public static class SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void EnableReactApp(this WebApplication app, string spaPath)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(app);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(spaPath);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(codePath); 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage(spaPath);
            });
    }
}

Then make a page that passes off to the react app named like your path spa1.cshtml:
@page

@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewData["Title"] = "React App";
}

@* Entry point for our react app *@
@* The id is the same as the one that react references in index.tsx *@
<div id="react-app"></div>

<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/vite.config.ts"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/vite.config.ts" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

Your react app, if running, would render where ever <div id="react-app"></div> is placed.

this solution doesn't use the useSpa() methodology. This should work even with the spa apps being hosted on separate servers which is why I am not pointing to files at the wwwRoot.
